# How to use SQL temporary tables in Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerquery, temporal-tables

I am building a Power BI report that uses a set of SQL temporary tables as source. I would like to provide the user the opportunity of selecting a month from a date slicer and based on that selection, the report would show the valid data AS OF that date.

SQL allows this by using system versioned tables that allow queries such as

```
SELECT * from table FOR SYSTEM_TIME BETWEEN 'date1' and 'date2'
```

which would give back all valid values in the table as if the query was run between those dates.

I couldn't find any documentation on how to work with temporary tables in Power BI.

What's the best way of doing this in power BI?

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't believe PowerBI supports this. You would need to build to the logic into your model and in the DAX.

Comment: Your requirement goes against the core concepts behind Power BI. Usually, the entire data set is accessed, and then filtered for the desired parameters, including dates. If your data is too large, you might either use Direct Query mode, or partition the data.

Answer (score 0):

I have just done this recently. @RADO is correct; For import mode, you have rows for each date (or month, in your case) in a Power BI table. All the work is in SQL.

First, I created a inline(-able) table-valued function that accepts a datetime2 for the SYSTEM_TIME AS OF clause and returns the desired resultset with in joins as needed.

```
SELECT 
    header.*, 
    detail.*
FROM header FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @utcTimeStamp AS header
LEFT JOIN detail FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @utcTimeStamp AS detail ON detail.header_id = header.id ;
```

You would have to adjust @utcTimeStamp so it gives the appropriate instant for your meaning of the date or the month.

```
--- Ajust to match your time period datatype
DECLARE @utcTimeStamp datetime2(3) = DATEADD(ms, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(@date AS datetime2(3)))) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Then, I created a view to cross apply the function against the dates needed.

When I found that it took a long time to query the view, I created a caching table and SQL Agent job to insert results from the last date through yesterday (at a time that ensures yesterday is over in all of our timezones). If you only need monthly results, you probably wouldn't need this step.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing now, is this not possible to do with the history table using the start/End Date. I don't know if so but this is what i was going to try. Am I right in thinking the above sql queries work in PBI? I was just about to ask a question but probably get a down vote for duplicate ;)